# Does Serenity BDD (JUnit-Maven) supports excel file access? need examples

Tags: java, excel, maven, junit, serenity-bdd

I have to come up with a poc for the test automation approach for one project & have been asked to look into serenity bdd.

I am able to use CSV for the project, however, prefer excel files with multiple sheets for the approach as the workflows demands lots of data.

Is it possible to access excel (xls/xlsx) files in Serenity BDD framework?
Can anybody please provide an example if answer to above question is yes?

I have searched for a solution thoroughly at my end, however, didn't find the way to handle it.

Probably need experts help, hence posted it here.

Comment: using POI you can directly do it and also there is no direct integration to Serentiy-bdd for excel (as far as i know), all you can do is to use the java jar like poi to do you task.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use csv as it is a direct use txt file. If you want to use excel, need poi dependency which can help you to fetch excel data or create one.
dependency
groupId org.apache.poi
artifactId poi
version 3.14

Comment: Thanks @user6414280 for the prompt answer, I tried using poi to access excel files, however, don't know much about the integration with serenity bdd, can you refer to an example or provide one? That'll be a kind help.

Comment: i have no idea about serenity. You are using maven junit, so  you can create a util class using poi to fetch data and import into your junit test class.